# Phonegap Application v.3.4.0 Ignores navigator.splashscreen.hide()

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, plugins

I have an iOS application that is running on Phonegap v.3.4.0.  I am attempting to use the `org.apache.cordova.splashscreen` plugin to eliminate the flicker on startup.  I have successfully installed the plugin using [CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) and prepared `config.xml` such that it keeps the splash page up until given the command to do otherwise.  However my javascript file is unresponsive to the command [`navigator.splashscreen.hide()`](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html) which is supposed to hide the splashscreen.  Any thoughts as to why this might happen?  The relevant code is below.

Many thanks.

---

**config.xml**

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

---

**bottom of index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/splashscreen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main_js_file.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been making two mistakes:

1. First of all I was directly sourcing `cordova.js` within `index.html` rather than allowing cordova to insert it when the app was built (in my case by XCode).  So you still need to place `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` at the bottom of the body, but it doesn't have to point to any doc.
2. Secondly I had placed my application in the wrong `www` directory.  Though it seems strange, I found through trial and error that Cordova 3.4 calls the index file in `AppName/platforms/ios/www` rather than that in `AppName/www`.

Answer (score 0):

Add an eventlistener in your script file to see if the device is ready (i.e)see if all files are loaded

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onProjectLoadComplete, true);
```

when the device is ready hide the splash

```
function onProjectLoadComplete() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

If this does not work.Please post the code as to where you are hiding the splashscreen.Make sure you have installed cordova devie plugin aswell

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I am using the event listener as you suggested above however the issue persists.  By "devie" plugin did you mean "device" plugin.  If so, I have not yet installed that.  I will try that and report.